# How to integrate Ping Federate IDP with OpenLDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap, pingfederate

I have configured OpenLDAP to store user information.

In Ping Federate, I have given the OpenLDAP connection information. LDAP connection has been established. I am using HTTP Basic adapter on the PF IDP side.
How to give search filter?I have given something like:
cn=$username.

The following is the User information in OpenLDAP directory server.

```
dn: cn=John Smith,ou=people,dc=highroads,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: John Smith
cn: John J Smith
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
userpassword: jSmitH
ou: Sales
```

On single sign-on authentication, I gave:
Username : uid
Password : userpassword

from the user information in OpenLDAP directory. But I am not able to access SP resource.

Please let me know about the configuration information I should provide on the Ping Federate side.

Thanks,
Aswini J

Answer (score 0):

You would manage this in your Password Credential Validator that you have assigned to the HTTP Basic Adapter. If the user is providing the attribute value stored in the "uid" attribute, then you would typically specify "uid=${username}" as the Search Filter and "dc=highroads,dc=com" as the Search Base for the PCV. You can make this more complex/specific as needed to ensure you only get a single user identity returned from your LDAP.